# Matching a path / url to a state in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a string path, generated by $state.href() somewhere else in my code.  I'd like to use that variable to find the $state object that matches that path (I assume this is what ui-router is doing internally to decide which state to transition to).

Comment: What's the purpose to locate that object?

Comment: It's too bad no one tried to answer the question you actually asked -- I also need to retrieve a state definition for a URL, outside of regular navigation, and cannot find info on whether the functionality is exposed anywhere. Even if I could just grab the urlMatcher instances & iterate myself it'd be good enough...

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.  It returns a state given any URL.  You'll have to extract out the angular path portion of the URL first.  i.e. the thing after the # sign.  You'll also have to inject $state and $urlMatcherFactory.

```
   var _urlMatcherForStateMaps = [];

  /**
   * Iterate through all states available in the app and return the first state that matches the specified url.
   * The URL matchers for the states are cached to not have to generate the RegExs outside of the first time this
   * app is called.  I don't think app states can change at runtime, but if I'm wrong about that the cache will
   * have to be cleared.
   * @param urlPath The relative angular url path to match.  This will not work with absolute urls.  You want to send 
   *                the path after the # i.e. 
   *                '/path/id' not 'http://host/#/path/id'
   * @returns {*} The state or undefined if one is not matched
   * @private
   */
    function _findStateForUrl(urlPath){

        //Build a cache of url matches for quicker access
        if (!_urlMatcherForStateMaps.length) {
            //Get a list of all available states in the order they are defined in app.js
            var stateList = $state.get();
            for (var i = 0; i < stateList.length; i++) {
                var state = stateList[i];
                var urlMatcherForState = $urlMatcherFactory.compile(state.url);
                _urlMatcherForStateMaps.push({
                    matcher: urlMatcherForState,
                    state: state
                });
            }
        }

        //Iterate through our url matches and return the first one that matches
        for (i = 0; i < _urlMatcherForStateMaps.length; i++) {
            var urlMatcherObject = _urlMatcherForStateMaps[i];
            var matches = urlMatcherObject.matcher.exec(urlPath);
            if (matches) {
                return urlMatcherObject.state;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access `$state.$current` (not $state.current). Especially it's properties `.parent` which allows you to traverse the tree and find the top (abstract) state. Mind that that the top state in this tree (with `parent==null`) is a system state `__inactives` which is not user defined.

Also you will use `.$current.url.prefix` to match URL of a parameterless state. This will however be a more complex matter to match URL for states with parameters

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

Add this to your config

```
$stateProvider.decorator('parent', function (internalStateObj, parentFn) {
// This fn is called by StateBuilder each time a state is registered

        // The first arg is the internal state. Capture it and add an accessor to public state object.
        internalStateObj.self.$$state = function() {
            return internalStateObj;
        };

        // pass through to default .parent() function
        return parentFn(internalStateObj);
    });
```

Then do this later any where:

```
var state_regexp = $state.get(state_name).$$state().url.regexp;
if(state_regexp.test($location.$$path)){
   //Yeah matched
}
```

NB: Remember to inject $state and $location

Answer (score -2):

From [the wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#activating-a-state):

> There are three main ways to activate a state:
>
> 1. Call $state.go(). High-level convenience method. [Learn More](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options)
> 2. Click a link containing the ui-sref directive. [Learn More](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref)
> 3. Navigate to the url associated with the state. [Learn More](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing).

It seems that you're trying to transition to a certain state using that `$state.href()` variable you have. If so, rather than using the url you get from `$state.href()`, you're probably better off using `$state.go()` to navigate to the state itself directly.

---

If you really want to do something with that state object itself, I'd recommend listening for [$stateChangeStart](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events). Here's an example:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (fromState.name === 'foo') {
      // do something with toState
      // toState === { name: 'bar', templateUrl: '/bar', controller...}
    }
  });
});
```